# What are the privileges or rights a client could get with the static resources (css/javascript files) on a typical java web server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, client-server

Ok, I'm a beginner so this maybe stupid but i afraid that clients can modify static resources (css/javascript files) on server if they can load them directly through URL path (Of course I have to put css/javascript files outside of WEB-INF folder).
If my hypothesis is wrong, could you give me links or quotes to help me expand my knowledge ? Thank you :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about legal rather than technical matters.

Comment: A user cannot change the resources on _your server_ unless the user has write access to your server.  However, a user can certainly download individual publicly available resources from your server to their own _local_ machine, view it, change it _locally_, and run it _locally_ (if executable like javascript).

Comment: Note that it's becoming decreasingly common to use packaging methods with a `WEB-INF` folder at all. For Spring projects, self-contained Spring Boot jars are the norm now.

Comment: @chrylis Yep i know that. However, that is the popular method for Spring projects only, what i mention here is just a simple java ee project with classic jsp-servlet style (i'm just a student), but.....thank for your time, i will keep it as a good advice !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user's browser requests resources from your server, they are performing a GET request.  This request will not directly change any file on your server.  The request will go through your web server and will be processed.  In the case of the resources such as css/javascript files, the web server sees the user is requesting the file and sends the contents of the file back.  There is no way the user can update the contents of those files on the server unless you write code on the server to allow them to update the files.  If the user has direct access to the server via ssh or other protocol and has permissions on the folder that holds the resources, they would be able to change them.

The whole process is much more complex for going through the web server, but for brevity left out here.  Here is a good article that explains what really happens when you go to an address in a browser:
https://medium.com/@maneesha.wijesinghe1/what-happens-when-you-type-an-url-in-the-browser-and-press-enter-bb0aa2449c1a